# Fix Windows 10 Automatic repair not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootable-media

So two days ago my Lenovo laptop instead of booting Windows 10 just showed a black screen. I shut it down and rebooted into Ubuntu. I tried to run `ntfsfix` on my Windows partition, it didn't find any errors but it set the 'dirty' bit. When I rebooted into Win 10 it started the Automatic Repair which didn't work. I tried then other methods of troubleshooting using the command prompt in Windows PE. `Chkdsk` didn't find any errors, so I removed the dirty bit and disabled the Automatic Repair since it was useless anyway. Now every time I boot into Windows 10, instead of the automatic repair trying and failing, I immediately get

```
System registry file is missing or contains errors
D:\Windows\System32\config\system
error 0xc000014c
```

Everything I tried has failed. Trying to reset gives "There was a problem resetting your PC". I tried to use restore points, there's no effect: I select a restore point, it does something, returns to the blue screen, I reboot and again no Win 10. What's the point of all these Win10 recovery options if they're useless?

Since the error says it's the registry, I tried to restore the registry files. Except the `RegBack` folder in `system32/config/` is empty! Apparently Win10 doesn't back up the registry files anymore, they are in the restore points. But the restore points don't work either, as I mentioned above.

I even tried to use my Win10 recovery USB that I presciently created a year ago when I got this laptop. Except now I can't even boot from that USB! When I insert my Linux Live USB, I can boot from it fine, so it's not a problem with the USB port or booting from USB. My Win10 recovery USB isn't even detected by Ubuntu. When I tried to insert the recovery USB in an old Win7 laptop, the file explorer didn't detect any files on it and offered to format the USB. So I don't know if the recovery USB is dead or whether there are some specific BIOS setups needed to boot from it (already tried disabling SecureBoot, enabling Legacy boot instead of EFI - still booting Linux from USB works fine, why not Win10)?

So, now the Windows half of my laptop is unusable. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the REGISTRY in __D:\Windows\System32\config\"system"__ is missing or bad, boot into Linux again as see if there is a REGBACK folder inside the __D:\Windows\System32\config__ directory if so replace the "SYSTEM" file with the REGBACK "SYSTEM" file. That should work unless there is also something else at fault there. Also, is the BIOS set to UEFI ? Windows 10 likes to have Secured Boot enabled, if so try that first, then reboot. Hope I helped.

Comment: @vssher that's what I tried, read my post more closely -  the **Regback** folder is empty so I can't replace the file. Yes, the BIOS is set to UEFI+secureboot, I only disabled them when I tried to boot from a usb. Thanks for the suggestions, anyway.

Comment: I guess I missed that part, that is only used if set in the Registry or 3rd party software. If all others fail, I would try a reinstall or Inplace Upgrade.

Comment: Another thing recommended online is bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd /fixmbr. But I don't have mbr, I have gpt partition table+UEFI so I am not clear if bootrec will mess it up?

Comment: I have used that before, but it will not fix the registry, only the Windows partition boot files. Next time, if your familiar with the Widnows Registry, turn ON the use of the REGBACK folder. 
Goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Configuration Manager
The set the DWORD (32-bit) ‘EnablePeriodicBackup’ to a value of 1 "0x00000001(1)", 
if is not there, create it.

Comment: You might want to try this article at Computer World (great magazine) "How to fix Windows 10 with an in-place upgrade install" https://www.computerworld.com/article/3262979/how-to-fix-windows-10-with-an-in-place-upgrade-install.html

Comment: @vssher I noticed that when I boot the command prompt in Windows PE there are some files (SYSTEM, DEFAULT and so on) in **System32\config** on the **X** drive which is where cmd starts in Win PE, not the **D** drive which is my Windows drive. These files are very old (from 3/2019, I bought the laptop from OEM in 12/2019) but  maybe I could use them to replace the broken ones?

Comment: I don't think so, I think the SYSTEM file in the config (configuration) folder is system specific, you may get into more problems. That is a very good question I have been searching for an answer. You can run Windows Setup.exe from it though, to do an inplace upgrade, you don't have to boot the Windows USB installer just run the Windows PE and then run the Setup.

Comment: Are you sure about setup.exe? The article from ComputerWorld you cited says otherwise, quote "You cannot run an in-place upgrade install using a bootable Windows installer or when Windows is booted into Safe Mode."